# Kruskal-Wallis across 3 groups non-significant, but regression of the same data very significant

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, kruskal-wallis-test, age

I have an issue regarding the significance of an association that I can't seem to get my head around, because using one statistical test it is significant and using another, it is non-significant (very very much so). It is an association between 2 variables:

- Age. Non-normally distributed.
- A biological variable. This is non-normally distributed but can be logged to make it normal. It can also be split into three categories (low, medium, high) and be analyzed categorically, and it is often done like this.

So I initially presented the data in a table, with the age reported as median and IQR across the three categories of the biological variable. I ran a Kruskal-Wallis on this and it came out as non-significant (p=.230). The ages across the three categories of biological variable are very similar, with a minor increase in age (both median and IQR) as you move from the 'high' category to the 'low' category.

I also ran a Pearson's using the logged biological variable to ensure assumptions were met and it came out as a significant relationship (r=-0.14, p=0.017). Graphically on the scatter with a regression line plotted there is also a visual relationship.

Can somebody please help me understand why?

Comment: I'd also add that the sample size is relatively large (250+)